# is it safe to use ViewBag for sorting and searching from controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
public ActionResult _ReservationSearch(string sortOrder,string currentFilter, string currentPhoneFilter, string searchString, string searchPhoneString, int? page,int? psize, DateTime date)
    { 
    ViewBag.currentSort
    }
    public ActionResult _RoomSearch(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, string currentFloorFilter, string searchFloorString, int? page, int? psize, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "roomName DESC" : "";
        sortOrder = (sortOrder ?? "roomName ASC");
        var pageIndex = page ?? 1; //MembershipProvider expects a 0 for the first page
        var pageSize = psize ?? 10;
        ViewBag.psize = pageSize;
        var SearchRow = "categoryName";
        var SearchRowFloor = "FloorName";
        int totalCount = 0;
        DateTime datef = startDate;
        DateTime datet = endDate;
        ViewData["startDate"] = datef;
        ViewData["endDate"] = datet;


        try
        {
            if (searchString != null || searchFloorString != null)
            {
                pageIndex = 1;
                ViewBag.currentFilter = searchString;
                ViewBag.currentFloorFilter = searchFloorString;

            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
                searchFloorString = currentFloorFilter;
                ViewBag.currentFilter = searchString;
                ViewBag.currentFloorFilter = searchFloorString;

            }
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userId"]);

            String Query = "select * from FGetRooms_session('" + startDate.ToShortDateString() + "'," + userId + ") r where r.room_id not in(select f.room_id from FGetRooms('" + startDate.ToShortDateString() + "') f inner join  FGetBookings() b  on f.room_id=b.room_id where ('" + datef + "' between b.start_date and b.end_date) OR ('" + datet + "'  between b.start_date and b.end_date)) and " + SearchRow + " like '" + searchString + "%' and " + SearchRowFloor + " like '" + searchFloorString + "%'";

            var dt = PageHelp.GetPagedList(pageIndex, pageSize, ref totalCount, Query, sortOrder);


            List<RoomDto.Rooms> data = new List<RoomDto.Rooms>();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    data.Add(new RoomDto.Rooms { rId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["room_id"]), rName = dr["roomName"].ToString(), Rate = Convert.ToDouble(dr["Rate"]), extraBed = Convert.ToDouble(dr["ExtraBed"]), status = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["status"]), cName = dr["categoryName"].ToString(), fName = dr["floorName"].ToString(), bName = dr["blockName"].ToString() });
                }
            }
            var dataAsIPagedList = new StaticPagedList<RoomDto.Rooms>(data, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
            return PartialView("_RoomSearch", dataAsIPagedList);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["d_err"] = ex.Message;
            return PartialView("_Error");
        }

    }
```

and this is my view

```
 <div class="th-inner">
       @Ajax.ActionLink("Room Name", "_RoomSearch", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, currentFloorFilter = ViewBag.currentFloorFilter@*, startDate = @ViewData["startDate"], endDate = @ViewData["endDate"]*@ }, new AjaxOptions
        {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "ListBox"
         })
  </div>
```

Comment: This is not code, You are just mixing code that must be in Models with Controller code. Did You learn the basic principle of MVC ?

Comment: You should probably get error in `_ReservationSearch` as it doesn't return anything. Is your code in the post complete ?

Comment: my code runs perfectly... i am just want to know is it safe to use view bag like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag is just a container that transfers data between view and controller. Your code is definitely save, cause of this is just a server-side code. Why have you decided that this code can be unsafe? With the same degree of success i can show you example of console application source code and ask the same. If i am not right, please, somebody, correct me in comments. Hope, this will add you a piece of clarity.

Comment: @Anish, i meant that this theory is pretty clear. These things are simpler than you think.)

Comment: **At first**, If to follow healthy sense, logic in controller just generates some constants which are passed as a parameters to action links.Logic can't be intercepted from anywhere cause of this is server-side code, if you meant this facet of safety. **At the second**,as passive proof, do you really think, that MVP Tom Dykstra will write unsafe code in [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)?